# Adding functionality for using the up and down arrow keys to select a table row

Tags: javascript

I need the help of an expert on my question below as it exceed and goes well beyond the level of knowledge that I have for programming in JavaScript.

Given the existing JavaScript coding below, how can I piggy back and add onto the existing coding so as to add functionality for a user to use their up and down arrow keys to scroll through the table, while they are scrolling through (btw the header column exempt) it would highlight the selected row and change its row color.

A point to note that if an existing table row is selected, and I hit my up or down arrow key, it would just move to and highlight the previous and next row. Some logic here is that I am guessing that one would need to find the row index to do this. Like I said, it is well beyond what I know how to do.

Much thanks and a huge appreciation for all your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results" class="scrollingdatagrid">
  <table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(
function() {
var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;

    for (var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t) {
        trow = trows[t];
        trow.className = "normal";
        trow.onclick = highlightRow;
    }//end for

    function highlightRow() {
        for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t ) {
            trow = trows[t];
            if (trow != this) { trow.className = "normal" }
        }//end for

        this.className = (this.className == "highlighted")?"normal":"highlighted";
      }//end function



  }//end function

)();//end script
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ecNj/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly not optimal, but as you're not using jQuery (or a similar library) you've incurred a lot of cross browser overhead. This should be backwards compatible up to IE8.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EYYgT/2/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

Only change here is the addition of the `tabindex`

```
<table tabindex='0' id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
```

**JS**

```
//From: http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_Cross_Browser_Event_Binding-yMd
var addEvent = (function( window, document ) {
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
        return function( elem, type, cb ) {
            if ( (elem && !elem.length) || elem === window ) {
                elem.addEventListener(type, cb, false );
            }
            else if ( elem && elem.length ) {
                var len = elem.length;
                for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
                    addEvent( elem[i], type, cb );
                }
            }
        };
    }
    else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
        return function ( elem, type, cb ) {
            if ( (elem && !elem.length) || elem === window ) {
                elem.attachEvent( 'on' + type, function() { return cb.call(elem, window.event) } );
            }
            else if ( elem.length ) {
                var len = elem.length;
                for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
                    addEvent( elem[i], type, cb );
                }
            }
        };
    }
})( this, document );

//derived from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924150/402706
function getpreviousSibling(element) {
    var p = element;
    do p = p.previousSibling;
    while (p && p.nodeType != 1);
    return p;
}

//derived from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924150/402706
function getnextSibling(element) {
    var p = element;
    do p = p.nextSibling;
    while (p && p.nodeType != 1);
    return p;
}

;(function() {
    var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;

    for (var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t) {
        trow = trows[t];
        trow.className = "normal";
        trow.onclick = highlightRow;
    }//end for

    function highlightRow() {
        for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t ) {
            trow = trows[t];
            if (trow != this) { trow.className = "normal" }
        }//end for

        this.className = (this.className == "highlighted")?"normal":"highlighted";
    }//end function

    addEvent(document.getElementById('mstrTable'), 'keydown', function(e){
        var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if((key === 38 || key === 40) && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey){

            var highlightedRows = document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted'); 

            if(highlightedRows.length > 0){

                var highlightedRow = highlightedRows[0];

                var prev = getpreviousSibling(highlightedRow); 
                var next = getnextSibling(highlightedRow); 

                if(key === 38 && prev && prev.nodeName === highlightedRow.nodeName){//up
                    highlightedRow.className = 'normal';
                    prev.className = 'highlighted';
                } else if(key === 40 && next && next.nodeName === highlightedRow.nodeName){ //down
                    highlightedRow.className = 'normal';
                    next.className = 'highlighted';
                }

            }
        }

    });


})();//end script
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this actually needs to be that long--you just need to keep the index of the currently highlighted row.

This has only been tested on Chrome (I don't have IE), but it should work.

```
(function() {


/**
 * Gets the tr at the specified row or column
 */
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
function getRow(row) {
    return tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr')[row];
}

// store these so we won't have to keep recalculating
var numRows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;

// index of the currently highlighted row
var curRow = 0;

// highlight the initially highlighted cell
getRow(curRow).className = 'highlighted';




// listen for keydown event
if (addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('keydown',keydownHandler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandler);
}



// handle keydown event
function keydownHandler (evt) {
    // return the old cell to normal
    getRow(curRow).className = 'normal';

    // increment/decrement the position of the current cell
    // depending on the key pressed
    if (evt.keyCode == 38 && curRow > 0) // up
        curRow--;
    else if (evt.keyCode == 40 && curRow < numRows-1) // down
        curRow++;

    // update the new cell
    getRow(curRow).className = 'highlighted';  
}


})();//end script
```

Comment: Looks like it will work but I get an error: "object doesn't support this property or method" -
window.addEventListener('keydown',function (evt) {

Comment: Like I said, it didn't originally support IE lt 9.  It should work now, but I have no way to test IE on my mac.  Here's a jsfiddle of the working code if you're using non-IE: http://jsfiddle.net/Ee7Gp/.

Answer (score 1):

I have create a demo using JQuery [here on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ivojis/1/)

In general, we have 2 task:

- highlight selected row
- choose next/prev row

To highlight the "clicked" row, I use this code

```
$("#mstrTable tr").click(function(evt){
   var element = $(evt.target);
   var tableElement = element.parents('table');
   tableElement.find('tr').removeClass('highlighted');
   element.parents('tr').addClass('highlighted');
});
```

To choose next/prev row, I use jQuery [tree traversal function](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) with some exception when there is no `tr` inside your `tbody`. Note that `keyCode` of left, right, up, down arrow are 37, 39, 38, 40 respectively.

```
$(document).keypress(function(evt){
          var highlightedRow = $("#mstrTable .highlighted");
          if (highlightedRow.length > 0) // table cell is selected
          {
            var tbodyElement = highlightedRow.parents('tbody');
            var trElements = tbodyElement.find('tr');
            var nextElement =  highlightedRow.next('tr');
            var prevElement = highlightedRow.prev('tr');
            trElements.removeClass("highlighted");
            switch(evt.keyCode)
            {
              case 40:
                if(nextElement.length)
                {
                  nextElement.addClass('highlighted');
                }
                else if (trElements.length)
                {
                  $(trElements[0]).addClass('highlighted'); 
                }
                break;
              case 38:
                if(prevElement.length)
                {
                  prevElement.addClass('highlighted');
                }
                else if (trElements.length)
                {
                  $(trElements[trElements.length - 1]).addClass('highlighted'); 
                }
                break;
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution which selects rows in table just like a windows file selection works.

add class multiSelect to you table and then place this code in a JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var selectionPivot; 
// code for selected rows. 
$('.multiSelect tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
var tbodyElement = $(this).parents('tbody');
var trElements = tbodyElement.find('tr');
if(!e.ctrlKey && (!e.shiftKey) ){   
  trElements.removeClass("row_selected");
  selectionPivot=$(this);
 } 

if(e.shiftKey){ 
var bot = Math.min(selectionPivot[0].rowIndex, $(this)[0].rowIndex);
var top = Math.max(selectionPivot[0].rowIndex, $(this)[0].rowIndex);
trElements.removeClass("row_selected");
for(var i=bot; i<=top; i++){    
trElements[i-1].className+=" row_selected";
}     
}  
else  { 
   selectionPivot=$(this);
   trElements.removeClass("focus"); 
   $(this).addClass('focus');
    if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
    }
    else {      
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    }
}
});

$(document).keypress(function(evt){
if(evt.shiftKey){
      var highlightedRow = $(".multiSelect .focus");        
      if (highlightedRow.length > 0) // table cell is selected
      {
        var tbodyElement = highlightedRow.parents('tbody');
        var trElements = tbodyElement.find('tr');
        var nextElement =  highlightedRow.next('tr');
        var prevElement = highlightedRow.prev('tr');
        trElements.removeClass("focus");
        switch(evt.keyCode)
        {
          case 40:
            if(nextElement.length)
            {
              nextElement.addClass('row_selected');
              nextElement.addClass('focus');
            }
            else if (trElements.length)
            {
              $(trElements[0]).addClass('row_selected'); 
               $(trElements[0]).addClass('focus');
            }
            break;
          case 38:
            if(prevElement.length)
            {
              prevElement.addClass('row_selected');
              prevElement.addClass('focus');
            }
            else if (trElements.length)
            {
              $(trElements[trElements.length - 1]).addClass('row_selected'); 
                $(trElements[trElements.length - 1]).addClass('focus');
            }
            break;
        }
      }
      }
    });
    });
```