# Javascript get content of previous element

Tags: javascript, this

i've a question about 'this'. 
With this i can get the content of actual element, but i want to get the content of previous element.

```
function deneme2(e){
 alert(e.innerHTML);   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/247m3xec/

Is there any function to get the content of child or parent element?

How can i achieve that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `e.previousSibling` and `e.parentNode`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Previous Sibling name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924086/how-to-get-the-previous-sibling-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
 function deneme2(e){
     alert($( "#"+ e.id).prev().html());   
  }
```

Or try the post of *Amit Joki*. This is the same, but my post with using JQuery api.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8uyzb4ww/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `previousElementSibling` which gives the previous sibling element to the current element.

```
function deneme2(e){
   alert(e.previousElementSibling.innerHTML)
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/247m3xec/2/)

Comment: What's the difference from `previousSibling`?

Comment: @Barmar: `previousSibling` may select other node types too (e.g. comment nodes or text nodes).  Note that `previousElementSibling` isn't supported in IE8 or lower.

Comment: @Barmar it includes text nodes and comment nodes too unlike previousElementSibling, which takes the previous element with node type 1

Comment: Do you think he really wants to get the `innerHTML` of a comment node?

Comment: @Barmar in this case, `previousSibling` will be a text node and will have CLRF characters. http://jsfiddle.net/247m3xec/7/

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment, thought you said `previousElementSibling` would get the text node. Now I see why you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't realy clear to me if you want the parent-element or the sibbling element. If you want the html of the parent element of e, you can use following code:

```
function deneme2(e){
   alert(e.parentNode.innerHTML);
}
```

If you want the html of the child-element of e, you can use:

```
e.children[i].innerHTML
```

With i being the index of the element.